# How to edit many lines at once in TextMate?

Tags: text-editor, textmate, sublimetext

I am testing my first Chromebook and its Caret editor. 
I would like to have the feature called "editing many lines at once" by holding CMD and clicking appropriate lines, like in sublime but much faster, [here](http://web.appstorm.net/reviews/web-dev/caret-its-like-sublime-text-for-chromebooks/) thread about it.

How can you have Sublime-like editing of many lines at once in TextMate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've answered your own question; to edit multiple lines at once in TextMate, you Command-click the places you want to edit. Is that not working for you for some reason?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a faulty installation of OSX which is a reason of this. I will try this again after I get my OSX from Apple care.